# reverse tr in a table

Tags: javascript

i have this code now i specifically want on this table to be reversed.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>comment1</td></tr>
    <tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>comment2</td></tr>
    <tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>comment3</td></tr>
</table>
```

i need

```
<table border="1">
    <tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>comment3</td></tr>
    <tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>comment2</td></tr>
    <tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>comment1</td></tr>
</table>
```

I used jquery to do it but i need javacript.

```
 $('table').html($('tr.widget_view_row_even').get().reverse());
```

can someone provide me javascript solution. thanks

**Note:** i just to do this reverse stuff for the table contain tr with class widget_view_row_even.

Support needed: ie7+

Comment: which browser are you targeting ?

Comment: any browser. actually i should strictly use javascript instead jquery library

Comment: any browser or all browsers? Quite the difference there.

Comment: thats not the perfect answer we are hardcoding as 0th element but i want specific element tr which has class .widget_view_row_even

Comment: Refine your question please.

Comment: Is it so hard to edit your question in order for us to understand clearly your needs and a provide a better help?

Comment: i edited it and already many were clear and replied with their answers

Comment: Right, you should follow their example. Anyway, have a look at this : https://gist.github.com/eikes/2299607.

Comment: check my answer and try to correct to make it better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the nearest solution for my question.
please correct the code to make it better using the same idea

**js fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/F93bB/2/**

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    var rows = table[i].rows;
    for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        if(rows[j].className == "widget_view_row_even")
            rows[j].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[rows.length-1], rows[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah it needs two days to accept our own answer

Comment: Glad you solved it, but you could at least say thank you to author of the original idea.

Comment: Oh yea, it's okay, just funny :)

Comment: I upvoted your answer thats how i thanked :)

Comment: I also upvoted your answer as more complete. Peace!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
function query(sel, el) {
  return [].slice.call((el||document).querySelectorAll(sel));
}

var tables = query('table');

tables.forEach(function(table) {
  var widgets = query('tr.widget_view_row_even', table);
  widgets.reverse().forEach(function(widget) {
    table.appendChild(widget);
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qyvML/3/

Comment: This answer provides exactly what OP wants, a script that changes **all** tables. +1

Comment: query thing works upto which ie version ?

Comment: `querySeletorAll` IE8+, `forEach` IE9+

Comment: but ie7+ is needed for me. thats the main thing

Comment: cant we do using something like getAttribute stuff. queryselector i knew which is almost similar to jquery..but it new

Comment: IE7?! Then use jQuery, that's the best you can do to avoid headaches.

Comment: but its a framework which doesn't have jquery and including it wouldn't be good. So i wanted to use plain javascript

Comment: You don't need `querySelectorAll` or jQuery to perform such a simple task. Come on..

Comment: You don't but I suppose this won't be the only DOM operation. If you're targeting IE7 jQuery is a no brainer.

Comment: yeah i already have jquery solution as mentioned in the question

Comment: Of course. But unfortunately/fortunately OP can use it, so we have a nice opportunity to remember some JS!

Comment: My question was posted before the browser requirement, I'll just leave it here for completeness, but the other answer should work in IE7 AFAIK.

Comment: @wared well I have read in an OP comment that I can't find no more. Maybe in a deleted answer. But this actually worths +1.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown All right. Too many updates here. That said, this situation would have been less confusing if susheel had prepared the question with more details before posting.

Comment: check my answer and try to correct to make it better.

Comment: @susheel "you answer" (or mine :) will not not work if you have rows with classes different than `widget_view_row_even`.

Comment: yeah that is fine..that is what i required. i want only to target this class. but my answer will work in lower version of ie too

Answer (score 3):

Purest and simplest javascript solution using [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore):

```
var table = document.getElementById('table'),
    rows = table.rows;

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[rows.length-1], rows[i]);
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/F93bB/

Answer (score 0):

> Best way to do is use JSON. and reverse the json object then render it
>   using javascript.
>
> ### Thanks

Ok

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="renderRows(1);">Desc</a> 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="renderRows();">Asc</a>
<div id="tbl_cmnt"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var commentObj = {0:"comment1",1:"comment2",2:"comment3"}; //your data
function renderRows(rev){
    var rows='', keys = [];

    for(var k in commentObj){ keys.push(k); }
    if(rev==1){
        keys.reverse();
    }
    for(var i in keys){
        rows += '<tr class="widget_view_row_even"><td>'+commentObj[keys[i]]+'</td></tr>';
    }
    document.getElementById('tbl_cmnt').innerHTML = '<table border="1">'+rows+'</table>';
}
renderRows();
</script>
```

I have just used one method.
There may is more. Also we can use array which is easy.
But most of the application send responses in json format.

Best Mahavir :)

Comment: Good idea, that would be great to elaborate a bit (explanations, code samples, etc...).

Comment: idea is good but thats not my requirement. i cant change the comments code its a cms framework(hp interwoven teamsite). did this way

Comment: +1 for sharing a data based approach. Enhancement : `var commentObj = ['comment1', 'comment2', 'comment3']`.